# how to create columns for a checkbox group in Bokeh

Tags: bokeh, bokehjs, pandas-bokeh

I have close to 50 items that can be checkboxed. The list is long. How can I create multiple columns, say 5 columns with 10 items each?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to make a `row` with 5 checkbox widgets, each with 10 items. There is no way to split up a single checkbox widget.